# Override docker file string/variable from command line

Tags: docker

The docker file that I am using have some variables that I need to modify, but from command line:
(this is a part of the docker file)

```
 JAVA_OPTS: " 
    -Dsomething.something.port = 3333
    -Danother.something.port = 2222
```

Is there a way that I can use to override the port value, but from command line when I use docker-compose up?
Thanks.

Comment: That's not `Dockerfile` syntax.  What kind of variable is it?  Can you include more code context or possible a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you'll need to use a variable in your Dockerfile and then use a `build-args` in your docker-compose file.

For example :

```
# Dockerfile
ARG someport
ARG anotherport
JAVA_OPTS: " 
    -Dsomething.something.port = $someport
    -Danother.something.port = $anotherport

# docker-compose.yaml
build:
  context: .
  args:
    someport: 3333
    anotherport: 2222
```

During the build, the port value set in your compose file will be used.

You can find more about the use of variable (with an example) [in the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args).

Comment: Ok, nice explanation. I understand now. But my problem is (I should have mention that also) is that the docker file is on a repository that I don't have access to modify it and commit the changes, so I need to take it as it is. I use docker-compose up command through an agent build  script. I though that I could somehow override the variable values without altering the file. But thank you for the explanation, I understand better now :)

Comment: Well, another solution then is to modify the `JAVA_OPTS` env var at runtime. I guess this is a java application, and JAVA_OPTS is a environment variable, so you can modify it directly in your docker-compose file whith `environment`. Here is [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)